# Is "The ravages of time" a romantic manga?

Tags: the-ravages-of-time

Is the manga romantic? Does it even have a female character?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what kind of question you are asking, but from the plot summary it does not appear to be a romance and also appears to be a chinese comic.

---

Plot summary from wikipedia:

> The Ravages of Time is a spinoff of Luo Guanzhong's historical novel Romance of the Three Kingdoms. It tells the exploits of Liu Bei, Cao Cao, the Sun family, and other people from that period, from the point of view of the two main characters, Feng and Liaoyuan Huo, whose names collectively form the Chinese title of the manhua.
>
> Sima Yi is the young, unofficial leader of the Sima clan, a highly successful and rich merchant family with strong influence in politics and the economy. Unknown to people outside the clan, the elders have long deferred their power to Sima Yi, believing that he will bring prosperity to their clan, due to his flair for spotting profitable business ventures at a young age.

It also does not appear to have a female in 'The Ravages of Time' chinese comic/manga ever.

Comment: Could it be because the Romance word in "Romance of the Three Kingdoms"? The Romance there doesn't mean as Romance in Love (take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romance). Whatever it is, Ravages of Time clearly not a book where you read it because you search for a Romance (in Love) as main theme.

Answer (score 1):

First, this question lacked of any amount of research. Please consider researching before asking questions, especially for queries that Google or Wikipedia can answer in less than a minute. It increases the load on the server.

Essentially, it's not. It's: Action, Drama, Historical, and Seinen. Of course seinen stories are free to have that element, but it's not a romance-centred manga.